# Create login form in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a login page in iphone, using `sqlite`.

I need suggestions ,how to create login form with username /password authentication.
For successful login - user should navigate to next page.
Otherwise giving user a error message: *login failed*.

Can you guys suggest me some tutorial or some guideline to create login form.

Comment: What is "perfect login authentication"? Why are you using SQLite? How can you log in a user without knowing their username? This question is a bit of a trainwreck.

Comment: @shaggy Frog.... so wat is the best way to create login form?

Comment: You still don't seem to understand the problem with your question as it is currently phrased: not only does your question not make sense, but you also haven't given any background as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you don't check. Could you explain a little bit more ^^?

But you have two options to show textView & co :
- UITableView with differents sections and rows.
- UIScrolLView

First create the User Interface. What do you need ?
- UITewtView for Login ?
- UITewtView for Password ?
- Checkbox for "cookie" ?
- Others options ?
- And Submit Input
Then Create the UI ^^

When you have your UI, just check informations, do the sqlite request etc.

If you have further questions... :-)

Comment: thanks Vinzius for ur kind  post.i do hv all necessary things to create a login, but the problem i am facing is, i m not sure, how to pass query for login. What code/query should i write and where should i write.??/ thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by passing query  ? where is your database ? on iPhone ? on distant server ?

Comment: yep. local database, its on iPhone ....

Comment: Ok next step, did you have what is required to do SQLite request ? did you do try one to test ? Do you know how to call a function when the submit button is pressed ?

Comment: yes..i hv attached database to my code, i hv button pressed event and al that stuff.but i m worried about what query should i passe and how to authenticate  that password from database, on the basis of that, if authentication gets successful, pass the user to next page otherwise show him authentication failed message.

Answer (score 2):

Why on earth is it relevant that you are using sqlite? That has nothing to do with a login screen. Go back and rewrite your question to be coherent, and I will rewrite this answer to be helpful.

Comment: hey Jonathan....i need to create local database,i dont need an external database, dats why i am using SQLITE. ANy suggestions now?

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't explain why on earth your database needs have **anything** to do with the construction of a login form. Perhaps you should split this question into two equally incoherent questions about different things.

Comment: I still have no idea what in the Galaxy you are asking, but on the off-chance that you are somehow wondering about caching a username so that the user need only enter a password, you certainly would not need a tool so heavy as sqlite for that. That would be like using an anvil instead of a needle to knit a sweater.

Comment: i just need to authenticate username and password from database...and on successfull authetication,, it should move to next page, otherwise it should give error message...dats all